# Name for a method used to navigate the lattice in lattice field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lattice-gauge-theory

I am currently working on a small code to calculate field configurations for $\phi^4$. Going through the literature, I stumbled upon a method for navigating a $D$-dimensional lattice by assigning each lattice coordinate to a unique integer. Letting the coordinates be denoted by $\mathbf{x}=a(n_0,n_1,...,n_{D-1})$, where $a$ is the lattice spacing, $D$ is the number of dimensions, and $n_i\in\mathbb{N}$, the integer corresponding to each coordinate is
$$j=\sum_{k=0}^{D-1}n_kL^k,$$
where $L$ is the number of points along each dimension (so the volume of the lattice is $L^D$). Is there a name for this method?

Source:
Lellouch, Laurent, et al., eds. Modern Perspectives in Lattice QCD: Quantum Field Theory and High Performance Computing: Lecture Notes of the Les Houches Summer School: Volume 93, August 2009. OUP Oxford, 2011.

Comment: This is just the obvious ordering of points in a lattice right?

Comment: It is just the trivial linearization of the lattice. It is like *column major layout* (or *row major layout*), just in four dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I recall using such a  one-dimensional  array for storing field configurations when writing lattice gauge code for a  Cyber 205 back in 1980's. There was a substantial overhead to setting up a higher dimensional  array, and also for "do loops", hence the one dimnsional array. I had  FORTRAN routines called MUPX, MDOWNX, MUPY  etc. for finding the address of neighbouring sites. I did not have a name for it though. I'd have though the need for such tricks was long gone!

Comment: My code is extremely simple compared to what's considered state-of-the-art nowadays. Since I asked this back in November, I've tried out a couple of home-brewed variations of it.